# Wild Ginger Bug Smells Like Buttered Popcorn. Keep or Toss?

Tags: ginger-beer, aroma, diacetyl-rest, first-time, popcorn

This is a two week old Ginger bug developed from organic store-bought ginger (not a SCOBY). I've kept it in a warm cabinet, not my fridge while it got established. I'm new to fermentation and brewing, this is the first thing I've ever tried to do.

Since my bug was nice and bubbly I started a primary ferment yesterday, but it's the bug itself that smells like move theater popcorn. I've read that that could be diacetyl (sp?) but could also be lactobacter?

I thought that ginger bugs were lactobacter cultures? If that's the case, is the buttered popcorn smell normal?

I put a heating mat on it and raised the temp to 80. Is there anything else I should do, or do I have this all wrong? Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Butter is diacetyl.  Yeast can eat it, so fortunately it ages out.  Typically this will take 2-3 weeks in beer.  I'm not sure how long in a ginger bug but my guess is similar timeframe.  So just be patient, and give the culture time to eat it.  Good luck!